# What is this error "Failed to execute org.gradle.cache.internal" which occurs when Sync project with Gradle file

Tags: android-studio, flutter, gradle, dart

I am trying to Sync project with gradle files in android studio (I actually am using flutter) but this error occurs(see below).I tried to invalidate cache and restart and still this problem persists.what is it saying and how to fix this?

[image: Gradle file sync]

Comment: How did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing your gradle cache by running this command on your terminal.

```
rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/
```

Then run `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` to rebuild the Flutter project.